# Replicate behavior of a Perl script in C#

Tags: c#, perl

I am looking at a piece of Perl script and it is doing something which is not comprehensible to me. The code looks like following:

```
  my $diag_cmd = pack("CCS", DIAG_SUBSYS_CMD_F, DIAG_SUBSYS_PWRDB, PWRDB_DIAG_PKT_LOG | $processor_select);

 my $diag_request_var = Variant(VT_ARRAY | VT_UI1, length $diag_cmd);
 $diag_request_var->Put($diag_cmd);

 my $reply = $p->SendCommand($diag_request_var, $timeout_in_ms);
```

I have some specific questions:

1. $diag_request_var->Put($diag_cmd);
2. I am not able to browse to definition of SendCommand. Is that because it is library supplied?
3. Do we have a c# eloquent of pack in .NET?

Comment: [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) has a pattern language that allows you to convert numbers or strings to a specific binary form. The rest of that code is pretty boring: `length($str)` gives the length of a string, `.` is the concatentation operator (`+` in many other languages), and `|` is just the bitwise OR operator. The things like `VT_ARRAY` are constants that were imported somewhere. What this *means* depends very much on the specific context, as I have no idea where they come from and what they contain.

Comment: What does the variant do?

Comment: dunno, it's just some function. It's nothing defined by Perl itself, so you should look at imported modules.

Comment: Looks like this might be relevant to your interests! http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE/Variant.pm  The second line is totally making an array of unsigned integers that is the same size as your packed command!

Comment: I actually have updated my question since I did not post the entire code. I think that will help us understand the larger context of the question.